# P4V save current state

Tags: perforce, p4v

I am using the perforce gui application P4V (not my first choice, but that's what I need to use).

Every time I close P4V and open it again I have to find my stream in a sea of countless streams, so that I can show my stream as a graph and also switch to the correct workspace.

Is there a way to save my current state when closing P4V so that when I open it again I can continue working with my graphs ready and my previous workspace already active?
Thanks

Comment: p4v **always** saves my current workspace and re-opens with that workspace. Perhaps your preferences files are corrupted, or there's a permissions problem? What platform are you on? What version of p4v?

Comment: I am using Perforce Visual Client/NTX64/2015.2/1312139 on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter. I do not believe this is a matter of permissions because i have the same permissions as everyone else on his project and im the only one that has to reset the workspace every time. I have a feeling there is some sort of preferrence that i need to find, but i am having trouble finding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: The issue here was a bug in the 2015.2 build of P4V around saving the state of the stream graph. It was fixed in the 2016.1 release.

Sounds like a problem with the preferences file to me. P4V should be saving all that state exactly as you describe.

How much customization of your preferences have you done? If it's minimal, I'd suggest just shifting the .p4qt folder in your user directory to the desktop or something and establish some preferences again from a clean state and see if the issue goes away.

If you've done a lot of customization already, support should be able to guide you to the specific setting keys in the preference files to remove, it's just fiddly.

Comment: I have done no customization whatsoever to the settings, except make some more tool windows visible. I also tried deleting the .p4qt folder as suggested but the state still isn't saved, and I still have to hunt for my stream again

Comment: Just to be sure, you ARE filtering down the stream graph before closing P4V, right? In the Graph View Options, you're filtering down the graph to just what you care about, and hitting "Apply"? Or is your expectation that the graph would remember where you had scrolled to in order to find your stream and stay centered on it?

Comment: I am filtering exactly as you said: select the correct streams and hit apply. Then I quit p4v and reopen and have to find my streams again and hit apply again. And so on...

Comment: So, I know there was a bug around this when I was working on P4V (awhile ago at this point) that I had fixed, and it MIGHT have gone out in the 2016.1 release of P4V. So it may well be worth upgrading the version of the client and seeing if that fixed it.

Comment: Yes! This was a version problem. Thanks a bunch! Works perfectly now that I have updated to the latest version

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it, I'll make a fresh answer that calls that out explicitly so anyone else that finds this easily gets the answer (if you want to approve it)

Edit: Actually, I'll just edit this answer.